# Has any Marvel superhero crossed into the Star Wars universe

Tags: star-wars, marvel

Marvel at one point was putting out one-off comics that had to do with a What If scenario in which one of their main characters did something completely against that characters main tenents.  During one of these type series did they ever cross into the Star Wars Universe?

We have seen examples of Marvel and DC crossing, and currently seeing Green Lantern show up in the Star Trek universe.  Most of these series are not canon but have seen print.

Comment: Meh. Wolverine in Conan's world is still my favorite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not at this time. While Marvel has published, and is publishing, Star Wars comics, there has been no official crossover comics between characters of the two. There has been crossovers with Star Trek (X-Men/Marvel, Green Lantern/Legion of Superheroes/DC, Doctor Who/BBC). With the acquisition of both Marvel and Lucas Arts by Disney, there has been other crossovers. A Disney cartoon property Phineas and Ferb has had crossovers with both Marvel characters and then a Star Wars parody. So the possibility exists, but the answer is **Not yet**.

Answer (score 6):

Although no actual comic concerning this has been released, the game *Disney Infinity 3.0*, the sequel to *Disney Infinity* and *Disney Infinity 2.0: Marvel Super Heroes*, does.

The gameplay of 3.0 focuses on the Star Wars characters Anakin Skywalker, Ahsoka Tano, Luke Skywalker, Leia Organa, Finn, Rey, Boba Fett, Yoda, Obi-Wan Kenobi, Han Solo, Chewbacca, Darth Vader, Darth Maul, Ezra Bridger, Kannun Jarrus, Sabine Wren, and Zeb Orrelios. In an area of the game called "Toy Box Takeover", the following plot unfolds: When Syndrome gets his hands on Merlin's Wand, he teams up with all the other villains, and it's up to the player to assemble every Disney, **Marvel, *and* Star Wars** character to stop him before he destroys the toy box.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**

Basically its The Star Wars crossing into the the Marvel comic but its a crossover nonethless.

There has been a crossover between the X-Men and Star Wars -

[image]

> The artist on the issue, a young Rob Liefeld, would be charged with filling several panels with alien creatures. A lot of those characters were pretty recognizable, and less parody as much as poorly drawn. While there has been no end to the amount of criticism slung at the Deadpool creator, it’s hard to argue against the points when your panels contain a hovering Xenomorph head, a depiction of Yoda after a bad night in Tijuana, ALF, and no discernible sense of scale. But, most telling of all, for as many characters as Rob tried to fill into a two-page spread there is only one visible foot amongst them. One.

Also a crossover with Guardians of the Galaxy -

[image]

> After the success of the film, the reenergized Guardians of Infinity paid tribute to the series that brought it fresh life and subtly nodded their approval to corporate siblings in one fell swoop. After using Rocket as a giant chalkboard eraser, the team discovers an ancient language. Rocket translates what appears to be the basic language of a galaxy far, far away. Thinking they’ve discovered a tomb, the team trudges on, but in reality, the text was the book's credits -- not the first stages of a universal civil war.

[Source](https://screenrant.com/star-wars-best-crossover-comics-must-read/)

Comment: I had asked a question regarding that exact X-Men comic:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191341/are-the-events-of-x-men-245-considered-canon.  The original point of my question had to do with the canonicity of clearly spoof comics but it was culled down to that specific issue of X-Men.

Answer (score 3):

In a matter of speaking, and I believe it to be an easter egg, but in *What If...?* 8th episode, the Watcher and Ultron fight and appear on a planet that looks like Mustafar. Vader’s castle can be seen in the background.

[Source](https://twitter.com/sw_holocron/status/1443961453644505094?lang=en)