# Are the events of X-Men #245 considered canon?

Tags: marvel, x-men, canon

*Uncanny X-Men* #245 reads like a parody comic, rather than a regular issue. This great comic has a host of ridiculous occurrences (near use of a 'Jean Bomb') and cameos (Boba Fett and E.T.).

It seems like a tongue-in-cheek one-off comic. I don't really remember any additional references to the events that occurred afterwards.

All that said, does that mean it is not canon?  Did Australia get invaded by an alien horde including someone that looked like Jabba the Hutt?

Comment: Some parody comics are fairly clearly out of canon. Power Man is not a girl, and Wonder Man is not a woman (from one of the *What If* parody issues, probably v1 #34 or thereabouts). If something in the issue is ultimately referenced outside it, then it almost has to be considered canon (mentioned because Jubilee first appeared in issue #244, and I think this issue happens in a mall, so I'm not sure if it's connected with her going with the X-Men back to Australia or not).

Comment: @RDFozz - What If comics were exclusively non-canon to begin with and not within main continuity.  I will edit the question to make that distinction.

Comment: @SDH - I've edited this to ask about *this specific comic*, rather than about similar but unnamed comics. This should eliminate the close votes about the question being too broad (it's hard to say whether other unnamed comics would be in or out of canon; saying so about this one should theoretically be possible). It could still be considered as primarily opinion-based, though.

Comment: I checked the letter pages for the next dozen issues. #245 is mentioned a few times but never gets an official comment in response.

Comment: @Valorum-Do you think you can put up a link to those letter pages? Will peruse them and also check Marvel Wiki and Comic Vine for additional information